# ï»¿ Appears at the beginning of my utf-8 text file when view as ANSI

Tags: c#, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have a text file and it uses utf-8, but when the users view it in ANSI unknown characters appear at the very beginning. I am using C#.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a BOM. Save as "UTF-8 without BOM" to get rid of it. Notice that Notepad does not support saving without BOM and you need a better editor to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a byte order mark.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode
>   character used to signal the
>   endianness (byte order) of a text file
>   or stream.